# Retry policy for SOAP over a ClientBase auto-generated class?

Tags: .net, wcf, soap

I have a class `TheServiceSoapClient` inheriting [ClientBase](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/ms576141(v=vs.110).aspx) that has been originally auto-generated by Visual Studio 2012 based on the WSDL associated with the remote web service based on SOAP.

```
var myClient = new TheServiceSoapClient();
var r = myClient.GetSomething();  // unreliable, need retry policy
```

Yet, the remote service is not very reliable and sometimes it fails, returning HTTP error codes like 403 or 500. I would like to implement a retry-policy that would let me intercept faulty responses and retry according.

How can I do that?

Answer (score 0):

Catch the  `InvalidOperationException` exception during the unreliable `GetSomething()` operation, and use an appropriate delay before retrying.

```
    retries = 0;  
    while (retries < retryLimit)
    {
       try
       {
           var r = myClient.GetSomething();
       }
       catch (InvalidOperationException exception)
       {
          retries++;
          System.Threading.Thread.Sleep(50);
       }
    }
```

Comment: Thanks, but isn't any way to inject somewhere a fault handler of some kind? I have many calls the soap client, and the reliability layer would need to be added everywhere.